# how to Detect Onclick event on iframe [cross domain ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am showing my site inside iframe. I want to detect user Agent, 
if user open this iframe on IE then onClick on the iframe user should navigate
to another site or if user browser is chrome or firefox 
then he should continue with site inside iframe.

Following is my code:

```
 <iframe id='iframeGoogle' name='a373563b' 
  src='http://google.com?header=true'  width='768' height='1024'>

             <script>  
                  $(document).ready(function(){
                // $("#iframeGoogle").click(function () {
                       var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
                       var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
                       if (msie > 0) {    
                         window.open="http://example.com"; 
                        // site should redirect to another  page if user agent is IE 
                       }
                      else                 
                      {
                        console.log("otherBrowser");
                      }|

                });  //});
             </script>
```

I have some finding on this, 
we can't recognize click event on iframe so what should I do now?

Comment: use window.open instead of location...

Comment: yes i will use that but my question is how to recognize click event on iframe .

Comment: while you're checking msie inside iframe, just use there...

Comment: where is your button? inside iframe or on the page where iframe is set?

Comment: Actually i dont have button, i am opening my example.com site inside iframe , if userAgent is IE  then on click on the iframe any where i want to open my site into another tab. and if its not IE then user could continue with site inside iframe. I am not able to detect click event of user on iframe

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work irrespective of whether the page is on the same domain or not:

```
 var iframeClick = function () {
    var isOverIframe = false,
    windowLostBlur = function () {
        if (isOverIframe === true) {
            // DO STUFF
            alert('in');
            isOverIframe = false;
        }
    };
    $(window).focus();
    $('#iframeGoogle').mouseenter(function(){
        isOverIframe = true;
        console.log(isOverIframe);
    });
    $('#iframeGoogle').mouseleave(function(){
        isOverIframe = false;
        console.log(isOverIframe);
    });
    $(window).blur(function () {
        windowLostBlur();
    });
 };
 iframeClick();
```

Comment: This does not seem to work with specific elements in my cross-domain iframe. If I add `$('iframe#embediframe').find('input#NextSubmit').click(function(event){console.log('clicked');});` to the line after your alert, I don't get any response in the console.